# Recent Custom Chrome in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, window

I am interested in implementing Custom Chrome into one of my C# Applications. As i kept searching the internet for libraries that already took care of the main code, i found this: http://wpfwindow.codeplex.com/ . However, this is from 2009 and we are now in year 2014. I am also using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop.

I wanted to know if this resource is outdated, or can it still be implemented today? I am trying to achieve an effect like this:

[image]

but, i would like the windows close, minimize, etc. buttons as well as the titlebar in place. Is there any way i can achieve this effect without having to completely rewrite the form?

Something like below, but with custom colors for the header, and the form buttons. I would also like to have the option to remove certain buttons (and keep only the close button)

[image]

I also noticed this "Warning" for the essential window: `Complete customization of WPF window can be done only when AllowsTransparency is set to "True", which causes that the window is software rendered which might be not as fast GPU rendering.` This also made me skeptical on if i should use it or not.

**Recap**

1) I wanted to know if this resource is outdated, or can it still be implemented today?

2) Is there any way i can achieve this effect without having to completely rewrite the form?

3) Would customizing the entire form make the rendering slower?

Comment: Reason for the downvote? I would love to improve my question.

Comment: Why not try the resource before just asking someone if it works?

Comment: @DLeh I have already tried it. I want to know if i "should" be using this outdated code. that was 5 years ago. Stuff changes.

Comment: There are plenty of other resources if you google it. StackOverflow isn't a good place to get people to do your research for you. Here's one from 2013: http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/

Comment: @DLeh If you would actually read my question, then you would see that i am asking questions about the integrity of the code, not just wanting people to tell me how to make a custom chrome window. I have done plenty of research. That is one of the reasons i posted this on stackoverflow. Also, another question i asked was pertaining to the rendering of the Custom Chrome.